# WordPress Dashboard not showing Up after Login only the top bar shows up

Tags: php, wordpress

I moved the site from a windows to a new Linux host
I did the same thing with another site very similar
The other one works fine
This one works but I cannot access the Dashboard
After log in from http:...mysite.com/wp-admin I am logged in but I can see only the top bar not the dashboard
[I am attaching a screen shot so you can have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbm8m.jpg)
If I click on the link at the top bar sends me to the page (top bar stays there)
No other options on the top bar like edit page etc .. only the admin welcome and logout option ( drop down ) to the upper right corner
I tried everything I could with no luck
Restored everything many times after unsuccessfully disabled themes, plugins
tried many different settings for wp-config.php
.htacces recreated

Comment: what happens when you click on admin on the admin menu?

Comment: Check the server error log, you might have some clues. I suspect you have some PHP modules missing that are required to run.

Comment: By clicking on Admin inside the drop-down (Upper Right corner > Howdy Admin)
Nothing happens

Comment: The only error I got in the error.log so far is
PHP Notice:  Constant MULTISITE already defined in /home/...../public_html/...........com/wp-config.php on line 70
PHP Notice:  Constant MULTISITE already defined in /home/..../public_html/.....com/wp-config.php on line 69
There are no such lines there I guess they exist in the include file ...
I don't think that that's the reason for the problem to be honest ....
I didn't manage to find them lines anyway

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by checking the dg6w8sjt8y_usermeta table to see if the user has administrator rights
I noticed that the prefix was the same but with some capital leters
It was DG6w8sjT8y_capabilities instead of dg6w8sjt8y_capabilities
I changed that and the problem was solved
Looks like WP for a reason probably within new installation WP does not update table entries but adds new ones
Or does not update tables but creates new Tables with different prefix
dg6w8sjt8y_capabilities was not updated but a new entry was created DG6w8sjT8y_capabilities
So the user was named admin but had no admin privileges

Masivuye Cokile,  Alexander De Sousa Thank you for helping.
Masivuye Cokile your comment got me to check again for admin priveleges.